# Web Application working if I manually build and deploy to Tomcat, but not under IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

So I have this web application. Here are some of the important parts,

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>biz.tugay</groupId>

    <artifactId>jsf-one</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsf-one Maven Webapp</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Framework -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jsf-one</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

and **web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
              version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

and **applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myManagedBean" class="biz.tugay.jsfone.MyManagedBean"/>

</beans>
```

when I manually do **mvn clean install** and copy the war file to webapps directory under Tomcat and run **startup.sh** , all will be fine.

However, if I try to run under IntelliJ I will get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)

May 10, 2016 2:03:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
```

What might be wrong?

**Edit: ** If I use the jetty plugin and do **jetty start** all will be fine as well..

I think this is a problem with IntelliJ but I am not sure what..

[image]

[image]

Comment: are all the spring libraries included in the web app artifact?

Comment: @NoeFernandez Yes they are. As I said, if I manually just go mvn clean install and copy the war file to tomcat webapps folder, everything works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039546/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-request-reques)

Comment: @Gangaraju No, it is not. This is an IntelliJ problem.

Comment: @KorayTugay do you use maven to run the application in Intellij? If you install the application via maven in the terminal all the dependencies in the `pom.xml` will be added. But if you use the tomcat plugin of intellij you have to specify in the artifact which dependencies are included.

Comment: @NoeFernandez - sorry, it's not correct that it's necessary to specify the dependencies. Declaring the dependencies in the `pom.xml` is sufficient. I use maven with IntelliJ and deploy to Tomcat both via maven or via IntelliJ Tomcat plugin. I don't have to specify the dependencies, only the artifacts itself.

Comment: can you tell us about your Tomcat-settings (Application Server settings) within IntelliJ? Take a look at [Tomcat settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601869/1988304)

Comment: @Ulrich I edited my question and uploaded 2 screenshots. I think there is something wrong with IntelliJ..

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Toray included the Spring dependencies in `pom.xml`, that's sufficient

Comment: Dont you require the maven apache plugin to make it work in IDE? I think so....maven compiler plugin...

Comment: @WeareBorg Sorry? Well there are other web applications in my computer that work fine with Tomcat..

Comment: what happens if you rename the directory `jsf - learning` so that there are no spaces within the name ?

Comment: @Ulrich It worked, thanks a lot.. Great catch and weird problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the directory `jsf - learning` so that there are no spaces within the name.

Answer (score 0):

Are the web.xml and other config files correctly detected/specified for intellij ?

And are the spring dependencies definitely included in the intellij artificat correctly ?

Comment: @KorayTugay in the project configuration (your second screenshot) , click on `Spring` under `jsf-one` and show us.

Comment: @Ulrich There is just one ApplicationContext shown and the applicationContext.xml file is seen there, so it looks ok..

Comment: @KorayTugay and what about web.xml

Comment: @NimChimpsky web.xml is fine as well. Please see the last comments under the question.